# Do I still need to submit my application for review to Facebook, even if the app is being internally used by my company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I have a question regarding Facebook's App Review submission message:

`App Review submission required by August 1, 2018 to retain access to Facebook Platform APIs`

Basically, in our application, that is written in Ruby on Rails, we have implemented a solution using the koala gem (creating a Facebook Application and using my user access token with `publish_pages` + `manage_pages` permissions that creates Facebook posts by the click of a button). I am an admin both in the Facebook Application and the Facebook Page we are posting to. This feature is only used by company employees, it is not even publicly accessable.

For implementation, it looks similar to this wiki guideline:
https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page

The review process described by Facebook totally does not match our use-case of the application, nor we do not want to grant access for a Facebook employee to our internal application.

Any enlightenment whether or not this Facebook Application should be submitted to review to Facebook or not would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it seems something more to send to facebook support directly

Comment: It’ll depend mostly on whether you will still be able to grant those permissions. I think Facebook is in the process of closing loopholes in that regard; it looks like in the future you might only be able to ask even people with a role in the app for those permissions, if the app is still in dev mode. Problem with that … all content created through an app is not visible to the public, as long as the app’s in dev mode.